# why does my if statement only runs the else part in android

Tags: android, if-statement

I'm trying to make a log in activity for my android app by connecting to the php server and matching the username password from database which is stored in the server. I retrieve statement 1 if the user is donor and 0 if the user is hospital. But in the following code the if statement always follow the else part even though the result is o.

here is my log in class

```
          login_hos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String   mUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String  mPassword = password.getText().toString();

            tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword);
            try {
                if (!response.equals("Login Error !")&&(!response.equals("Connection Error !"))){
                    String arr[]=response.split(",");
                    String type=arr[1];
                    type.trim();
          // String usr="donor";


        if (type.equals("0")) {
                            Log.v("type", type);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    HospitalHome.class);
                            intent.putExtra("user_name", arr[0]);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.v("type", type);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    DonorHome.class);
                            intent.putExtra("user_name", arr[0]);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }






                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: when you debug the application what is the value of "type" (at the `if`???)

Comment: you sure it's 0 (the number zero) vs "O" (the letter 'O')? (i'm just guessing here)

Comment: Show the code where `response` is assigned?

Comment: String is immutable, you have `type.trim();` where you should have `type = type.trim()`. perhaps you have some extra whitespace.

Comment: Unless you can tell from your log whether it has whitespace, he's probably right.

Comment: @DavidM Thank you now it's working.. (type=type.trim()) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try logging your type BEFORE the if-statement. To actually see what the type is.

As in :

```
 Log.i("Type", type);
 if (type.equals("0")) {
                        Log.v("type", type);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                HospitalHome.class);
                        intent.putExtra("user_name", arr[0]);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

Also when logging it's a good practice to create a `final String TAG = "myActivity"`; as a class attribute and then adding that TAG in this way : `Log.i(TAG, "thingIwanttolog");`

Comment: either the value of type=1 or 0 it always directs to the DonorHome.class ! that's the problem..

Comment: Check in logcat what `Log.v("type", type);` logs. Also make sure you (as David M said) set the result of `type.trim()` back in `type`. As in `type = type.trim();`